# UIToolbar as inputAccessoryView moves over UINavigationbar when rotating the iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uitoolbar

`UIToolbar` over `UINavigationBar` on rotation. When coming first time its showing perfect but when I rotate it moves over navigation bar.
How can I solve this issue? Please suggest.

See the image below for more information

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using framework like `IQKeyboardManager` for keyboard management?

Comment: yes, But normal inputaccessory view that i created also moves up like this on rotation

Comment: I suggest you to read `IQKeyboardManager ` docs, also, take a look at issues of the lib on Github repo, maybe they have solution for this.

Comment: You could also hide the toolbar, if it's not crucial for you (described in docs).

Comment: I need the accessoryinput view at some places that are causing issues